# Showing square blocks only in place of the arabic character

Tags: css, webfonts

I convert a jannaltregular.ttf. And then create the .php,.rar,.zip file using this link http://fonts.snm-portal.com/

But its showing question mark blocks only in place of the arabic character. Can you please help. Also please assist me to choose right arabic font selection.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be php or programming related.

Comment: Here you are talking about [tag:css] and [tag:webfonts] not about PHP. You have to show the CSS code that you have used to load the web font. Also, you have to be sure that font "jannaltregular.ttf" supports Arabic glyphs or not.